# To simplify the code (for a beginner)

Tags: c#

I'm on my first week of studying C#.
I guess there should be some way to use 1 "While()" condition instead of 2 in the code below. Is there any way to make my code more simple:

```
/* ask the user to guess a number.
        any number between 10 and 20 is the RIGHT choice, 
        any other number outside of that scope is WRONG. */
        int num;
        Console.WriteLine("[Q] Quit or make your choice");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer == "Q" || answer == "q")
            Console.WriteLine();
        else
        {
            num = Convert.ToInt32(answer);
            while (num < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try again");
                num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            while (num > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try again");
                num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Your number is {0} and it's RIGHT", num);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: You're already using the or operator (`||`) in the if condition earlier. Just do the same thing in the while condition.

Comment: So simple! Thanks! 
I was struggling by using && inside While() but that gave me the unexpected result.

Comment: This belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OR` operator to combine both conditions:

```
/* ask the user to guess a number.
   any number between 10 and 20 is the RIGHT choice, 
   any other number outside of that scope is WRONG. */

int num;
Console.WriteLine("[Q] Quit or make your choice");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();

if (answer == "Q" || answer == "q")
    Console.WriteLine();
else
{
    num = Convert.ToInt32(answer);
    while (num < 10 || num > 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try again");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your number is {0} and it's RIGHT", num);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```